# I am having a problem of this python code not stopping when it is conditioned to stop. why is it not stopping?

Tags: python

I am running all of this on a raspberry pi 4 model B with 8 gigs ram

```
import time

#sets variables and inputs
i = 0
meow = True
print("How many :")
runtimes = input("reo ")

#the main loop
while meow == True:
    i=i+1
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    if i == runtimes :
        print("stopping")
        meow = False
```

Comment: The result of `input()` is a *string*.  The integer value of `i` will never be equal to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:
`runtimes = input("reo ")`

To this:
`runtimes = int(input("reo "))`

What is currently happening is if you were to enter a `1` the value of runtimes would be `"1"`

When `i=1` and this is ran `if i == runtimes :` It would be checking to see if `1 == "1"` which would return `False`